# ROS Foxy on Ubuntu 20.04 : source command keeps failing fails

Tags: raspberry-pi3, ros, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to run ROS Foxy on my Raspberry Pi 3b+ on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS (Pi version). However, after following the tutorial by Articulated Robotics, (https://youtu.be/uWzOk0nkTcI), from his getting ready to build robots with ROS series, I can't seem to get the source command to work.

Whenever I try the source command `source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash` as shown in the tutorial, it displays this error:

> -bash: /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash: No such file or directory

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsrer.png)

Any idea on why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: Does the file `/opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash` exist?

Comment: I do not know how Im able to know this as im working over ssh from my base computer (laptop) running the same ubuntu mate 20.04 (desktop version here).
A point that i missed to include, i did follow this link as in the video (https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html) which did have some changes in the commands. These are the commands i ran in order:

Comment: `sudo apt install software-properties-common` 

`sudo add-apt-repository universe` 

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl -y` 

`sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg` 

`echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(. /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null` 

`sudo apt update` 

`sudo apt install ros-foxy-desktop python3-argcomplete`

Comment: This is excluding the sudo apt upgrade command so that Ubuntu does not upgrade to 22 jammy jellyfish making the use of Ros foxy not viable.

i understand that this is hard for you to read but this was the best i could do. Sorry!

Comment: You need to go back and make sure all of those install steps completed correctly. I'm fairly certain one is failing. You can verify that ROS is installed via `ls /opt/ros/foxy`.

Comment: Hey, im sorry if i had wasted your time but yes you were correct, tried the steps again and apparently a whole lot of files were not installed.
Thank you!